# list index out of range issue, variables not existing yet

Tags: django, django-views

I am quite a beginner in python django and I am running through an issue that I guess I know how to solve but  Iam not sure it is the right way to do it and  I would like to have your point of view.

My app is the following: 
A user create a project >> then create a team >> then invite member to the team >> is redirect to the project detail view

The reverse is following the team member invitation.

It is a questionnaire app so each invited members need to answer it and the answers is saved in "Response" and then I render the results in a dashboard.

All my methods for the dashboard are in my views.py.

My problem is that after inviting members all my methods are ran in the background but most of the variables do not exist yet since the invited user has not answered the questionnaire yet and I get an error like list index out of range

is there a way to fix that without using an if/else/pass ?

Method example :

```
def get_current_team(self, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    current_team_member = Project.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
    members_response_list = []
    for member in current_team_member:
        member_id = member.id
        member_response = get_user_response(member_id)
        members_response_list.append({member_id:member_response})

    return members_response_list
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What "variables do not exist yet"? What exact errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, but a simple if/return will do it. Your mistake is on the `Project.objects.get` call. Can't test it right now, but almost sure that `Project.objects.get` will throw an exception if the id does not exist. Consider:

1. Checking if `self.kwargs['pk1']` is diferent than None or
2. `Project.objects.find(id = self.kwargs['pk1']).first()` will not trow you an exception, but CHECK afterwards if the return is diferent than None
3. NEVER chain atribute access before checking if the object is None, or adding try/catch.